# iText for .NET barcode

Tags: itext, barcode, ean-13

I try to create a PDF with a **EAN13** Bar-code using the iTextSharp library.
I try to generate a  barcode with the value "**023942432852**".

```
iTextSharp.text.Image imageEAN = codeEan.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
```

throws `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

There is the code:

```
Document pdfdoc = new Document(pageSize, _margSx, _margDx, _margUp, _margBo);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, new FileStream(_path + @"\Barcode.pdf", FileMode.Create));


            pdfdoc.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            pdfdoc.PageSize.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY;


            BarcodeEAN codeEan = new BarcodeEAN();
            if (CreaChecksum)
                codeEan.GenerateChecksum = true;
            codeEan.ChecksumText = true;
            codeEan.CodeType = Barcode.EAN13;
            codeEan.Code = barcode;

            iTextSharp.text.Image imageEAN = codeEan.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
            imageEAN.ScaleAbsolute(100, 40);
            imageEAN.SetAbsolutePosition(pdfdoc.PageSize.Right - 150f, pdfdoc.PageSize.Bottom + 30f);   
            pdfdoc.Add(imageEAN);
```

Comment: At a guess, it is failing because the barcode specified is only 12 digits long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name indicates an EAN13 bar code requires 13 digits, just like an EAN8 bar code requires 8 digits. You are trying to create a bar code for this `string`:

```
"023942432852"
```

When I count the number of digits in this `string`, I only find 12. One digit is missing. Please complete the `string` so that its length is 13.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.