# iText7 for .NET barcode

Tags: c#, .net, itext, barcode, itext7

I'd like to create pdf with barcode using Itex7 library.
There is a lot of examples using older version of Itex, or Java, but I can't find solution for Itex7.
(generally new lib has no implementation of createImageWithBarcode method)

My solution could look like as:

```
string outputPdfFile = @"c:\DEV\pdfFromScratchWithBarCode.pdf";
using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(outputPdfFile))
{
    using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer))
    {
        iText.Layout.Document doc = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf);
        doc.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("Title"));

        iText.Barcodes.BarcodeInter25 bar = new iText.Barcodes.BarcodeInter25(pdf);
        bar.SetCode("00600123456");

        //HOW TO ADD barcode TO PDF ??
        // ...
    }
}
```

There is similar answer but for older version: 
[iText for .NET barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936809/itext-for-net-barcode#new-answer?newreg=51963a9a1a154c29b64a94a39c225dd3)

Comment: At first glance, it's `bar.PlaceBarcode` and you need to pass that a PdfCanvas. See the Inter25 unit test: https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext.tests/itext.barcodes.tests/itext/barcodes/BarcodeInter25Test.cs But I don't know iText7 myself.

Comment: I don't know the library, sorry. I'd guess the equivalent Document-type object is a Canvas, so maybe you can wrap the PdfCanvas in a Canvas then there might be ways to specify where that's positioned within the Document? (here's another question with a code sample that does this, via wrapping the PdfCanvas in a Canvas in a Rectangle: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51953204/243245) Or if you're working with PdfPages not Documents I guess there's positioning options there too.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for advices.

I found the solution (create pdf, add barcode {type: Code 25 – Non-interleaved 2 of 5} and set valid postion)

```
using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(outputPdfFile))
{
    using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer))
    {
        iText.Layout.Document doc = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf);
        doc.Add(new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("Title"));

        //barcode
        iText.Barcodes.BarcodeInter25 bar = new iText.Barcodes.BarcodeInter25(pdf);
        bar.SetCode("0600123456");


        iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas canvas = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas(pdf.GetFirstPage());
        //bar.PlaceBarcode(canvas, iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.BLUE, iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.GREEN);

        iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject.PdfFormXObject barcodeFormXObject = bar.CreateFormXObject(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.BLACK, iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.BLACK, pdf);
        float scale = 1;
        float x = 450;
        float y = 700;
        canvas.AddXObject(barcodeFormXObject, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image from a PdfFormXObject by doing this:

```
var barcodeImg = new Image(bar.CreateFormXObject(pdf));
```

Here is your code including changes that does the trick:

```
string outputPdfFile = @"c:\DEV\pdfFromScratchWithBarCode.pdf";
    using (var writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(outputPdfFile))
    {
        using (var pdf = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer))
        {
            var doc = new Document(pdf);
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Title"));

            var bar = new BarcodeInter25(pdf);
            bar.SetCode("000600123456");

            //Here's how to add barcode to PDF with IText7
            var barcodeImg = new Image(bar.CreateFormXObject(pdf));
            doc.Add(barcodeImg);        
        }
    }
```